# How do I add information to a PFObject without creating an entirely new one?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I understand it better now thanks @dbarthelemy. However here is my code now and I am getting an error/termination of no "results matched the query":

```
- (IBAction)createGroup:(id)sender {
    PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Messages"];
    [message setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
    [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDate" sender:self];
    }];
}
```

And then on the second controller:

```
PFQuery *message = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
            [message getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"recipientIds" block:^(PFObject     *message, NSError *error) {
                [message setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
                [message setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
                [message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
                [message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
                [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
```

Comment: Be sure to ask this question on the Parse forums also if you haven't done so already

Answer (score 0):

In createGroup: method, please make sure you are saving the PFObject to Parse using one of the save methods (e.g. saveInBackgroundWithBlock:).

```
- (IBAction)createGroup:(id)sender {
PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Message"];
[message setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
[message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
```

Then share the PFObject with your separate viewController class (using a property), and then set the additional PFObject attributes using this pointer (instead of creating a new PFObject using the objectWithClassName:). 
After having set the additional properties, don't forget to save the updated PFObject.

```
[self.message setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
[self.message setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
[self.message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
[self.message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
[self.message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
```

Note: if you cannot reliably share the PFObject pointer between various view controllers, you can execute a [PFQuery](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html) on Parse server to retrieve your object (assuming you can build the proper query).

Comment: I have updated my above code to show my current state/issue. thanks for your help @dbarthelemy

Comment: You cannot use getObjectInBackgroundWithId: to retrieve PFObject based on a custom key (recipientIds). Instead you should use the whereKey:equalTo: method (assuming that self.recipients is not a collection) combined with getFirstObject method.
Note that for a better clarity, you could name your PFQuery instance with a different name (e.g. myQuery) and make sure you are reserving 's' to collections and not object or key naming.

Comment: Does it help fixing your issue ?